# Removing hierarchical pages in the permalink

Tags: permalinks, pages, urls

I have several pages set up in a hierarchy on my site. Currently the site's pages and URLs look like this.

```
Page name        | Current URL           | Preferred URL 
-----------------|----------------------------------------
Page AAA         | /pageAAA/             | /pageAAA/
|-- Page BBB     | /pageAAA/pageBBB/     | /pageBBB/
Page CCC         | /pageCCC/             | /pageCCC/
Page DDD         | /pageDDD/             | /pageDDD/
|-- Page EEE     | /pageDDD/pageEEE/     | /pageEEE/
```

I would like to strip the page hierarchy from the URL and just use the page name instead. Currently this is not a problem for the "POSTS" as I have set the "Permalink" to `/%postname%/`

**Edit:** The reason that I want to do this is; I am importing a existing site into wordpress. The Existing site has a hierarchy for the pages (menu) but a flat url structure. I do not know if this has any added benefit for SEO but I want to keep the URL structure the same as the old site

Comment: Is there any reason to do this? From SEO point of view it could be the plus. `example.com/Kodak/Kodak-1234/` is OK. Can you precise, please?

Comment: Why create a hierarchy at all, then?

Comment: @MaxYudin I do not know if there is a added SEO benefit,

Comment: @vancoder I want the hierarchy for the menu system in wordpress.

Comment: You can create your own hierarchy in the menu system...? It's independent of parent/child pages.

Comment: @vancoder I currently have 100s of pages with a huge hierarchy in wordpress, new pages get added all the time. It would take a lot of work to manually create the hierarchy with a custom menu and extra effort to add the newly created pages to the custom menu every time I add a new page. instead of doing in on creation of the page.

Comment: Fair enough....

Comment: Curious: How did you get this permalink structure to begin with? I'm trying to figure out how to do this to begin with, and having difficulty.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be curious if someone can find a better solution to this. Here's what I came up with:

```
function wpse_91821_flatten_page_paths( $wp ) {
    if ( false !== strpos( $wp->matched_query, 'pagename=' ) && isset( $wp->query_vars['pagename'] ) && $wp->query_vars['pagename'] && false === strpos( $wp->query_vars['pagename'], '/' ) ) {
        if ( !get_page_by_path( $wp->query_vars['pagename'] ) ) {
            $page = get_posts( array(
                'name'        => $wp->query_vars['pagename'],
                'post_type'   => 'page',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'numberposts' => 1
            ) );
            if ( $page && isset( $page[0] ) ) {
                $wp->query_vars['pagename'] = get_page_uri( $page[0]->ID );
                $wp->request = $wp->query_vars['pagename'];
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'parse_request', 'wpse_91821_flatten_page_paths', 5 );
```

What I'm doing here is intercepting `parse_request` and if it's a pagename request, and the pagename doesn't have a "/" in it, then I check to see if I can find a post with the correct name. If I find a page, I set the query var, which allows the rest of the request chain to proceed as normal, because WordPress *thinks* the request is the full hierarchical one.

You'd also want to add a filter to `post_type_link` so that your links are generated correctly (otherwise they'll continue to be hierarchical).

Comment: I think you have to be very careful using this solution. I don't think it takes care of assuring unique post_names (am I missing something?) for these pages. So you may end up with multiple pages with the same post_name, so you won't be able to access some of them.

Comment: That's a great question. I'm not sure offhand if page names need to be unique, and if they aren't, if other issues arrive. I'll do some testing when I have some free time and report back on my findings. Thanks!

Comment: Of course they have to. Otherwise WP would not know which page to show based on permalink. Let's say you have 3 pages with `post_name='contact'`. Which of them should be displayed when you go to http://yoursite.com/contact? That's why WP has built in functions to assure that `post_names` are unique (and they change your `post_name` if it creates conflict). But these functions allow you to have same `post_name` for pages, if they have different parents. Your code will break this feature, I guess.

Comment: I'm not sure this solution is valid with WordPress 4.5.3 - I couldn't get it to work anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't change page permalink behavior. Much simpler/safer solution will be to set flat page hierarchy (if you really want it to be flat).

If you want to have hierarchy in menu, you can still have it - you can create custom menu and display it with `wp_nav_menu` function.

Answer (score 0):

```
function wpse_91821_flatten_page_paths( $wp ) {
    if ( false !== strpos( $wp->matched_query, 'pagename=' ) && isset( $wp->query_vars['pagename'] ) && $wp->query_vars['pagename'] && false === strpos( $wp->query_vars['pagename'], '/' ) ) {
        if ( !get_page_by_path( $wp->query_vars['pagename'] ) ) {
            $page = get_posts( array(
                'name'        => $wp->query_vars['pagename'],
                'post_type'   => 'page',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'numberposts' => 1
            ) );
            if ( $page && isset( $page[0] ) ) {
                $wp->query_vars['pagename'] = get_page_uri( $page[0]->ID );
                $wp->request = $wp->query_vars['pagename'];
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'parse_request', 'wpse_91821_flatten_page_paths', 5 );

function custom_permalinks_page_link( $permalink, $post_id ) {
    if ( empty( $post_id ) ) return $permalink;
    $post = get_post( $post_id );
    return home_url( $post->post_name . "/");
}
add_filter( 'page_link', 'custom_permalinks_page_link', 10, 2 );

function custom_rewrite() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^([^/]+)?', 'index.php?pagename= $matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_rewrite' );
```

As of wp 4.7, you would need to work around the parse_request: as `use_verbose_page_rules` is triggered and `get_page_by_path` call checks the `page` parents and their presence in the url(!) - this unexpected core check could be avoided by adding an **evil** space as in https://github.com/weaveworks/wordepress/blob/master/plugin/wordepress/wordepress.php#L91

This is, of course, very fragile and should be probably avoided :)

This presentation may contain a better answer but I was not able to comprehend it: https://www.slideshare.net/MikeSchinkel/hardcore-url-routing-2014?next_slideshow=1